# Fill data based on random forest object predicted response

Tags: r, random-forest

Using `randomForest`, I get an RF object.
E.g. `forest <- randomForest(as.formula(generic),data=train, mtry=2)`)

Using `predict` I can predict the response on a test dataset.
The response is either A,B or C.

```
prediction <- predict(forest, newdata=test, type='class')
mytable <- table(test$class_w,prediction)
sum(mytable[row(mytable) != col(mytable)]) / sum(mytable)#show error
```

Calling the forest object I get the confusion matrix:

```
     A     B    C     class.error
A   498    79   170   0.3333333
B   115    353  237   0.4992908
C   96     99   967   0.1678141
```

E.g **test dataset**:

```
id |class_w| valueA | valueB |
1  |  C    |  0.254 |  0.334 |
2  |  A    |  0.654 |  0.334 |
3  |  A    |  0.554 |  0.314 |
4  |  B    |  0.454 |  0.224 |
5  |  C    |  0.354 |  0.332 |
6  |  C    |  0.264 |  0.114 |
7  |  C    |  0.264 |  0.664 |
```

I would like to know if I can create a new dataset with 2 columns the id of the previous dataset and the predicted response (the RF gave). 
E.g.

```
row id of test dataset  |  predicted response
1                       |  A  #failed
2                       |  B  #failed
3                       |  B  #failed
4                       |  B  #TRUE!
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi joran. I mean, if it is possible, to know the predicted value for every row in the dataset and accomplish that by using a function that would mark the response like df$RF_Prediction <- predicted_value

Comment: I still don't understand. Are you just trying to do `test$RF_prediction <- prediction`? They should be in the same order. (And don't you mean `type = "response"`?)

Comment: I will edit the question give me a minute

Comment: I still don't really understand your confusion. This is no different than creating any other data frame: `data.frame(id = test$id,response = prediction)`. Or you could add it as a column to `test` as I noted above.

Comment: Joran, I think this is what I was asking. I am just starting using R, I didn't know how to do it. Post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I was confused because it seemed like from your question that you understood more about data frames than I guess you did.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28689/discussion-between-kabamaru-and-joran)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may simply be looking to create a new data frame:

```
data.frame(id = test$id,response = prediction)
```

That assumes that `id` is in fact a column in `test`, rather than the row names. If they are rownames, then you'd want to do:

```
data.frame(id = rownames(id),response = prediction)
```

Answer (score 1):

An another way to do that would be to just write something like this:

```
yourNewDataSet$someNewColumnCreated= Predict(forest,yourNewDataSet,type="class")
```

This should give you a new column in your new dataset named 'someNewColumnCreated'

that will contain all the prediction of your model when applied to this new data set.